# Providing custom variables for Info.plist

Tags: xcode, plist

In Xcode, you can edit an app's Info.plist, and you will see a number of variables that are inserted into the plist dynamically.

In the following screenshot you can see for example:

- EXECUTABLE_NAME
- PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
- PRODUCT_NAME

[image]

#### My question: how do you create your own variable for inclusion in the plist?

I would like to add the Build Date to the plist, dynamically generated every time Xcode creates a new build. However I cannot see where to set up the variable for dynamic inclusion as per the system-provided examples above.

I've tried `export BUILD_DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')` in a build phase but putting `$(BUILD_DATE)` as a plist value just isn't giving me anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions to add key/values dynamically to your Info.plist:

**Preprocess Info.plist file**

1. In `Build Settings` set `Preprocess Info.plist file` to `Yes`.
2. Then set `YourProject/Info.h` to `Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File`
3. Create Info.h file with next content and add it to your project:

```cpp
#define BUILD_DATE __TIMESTAMP__
```

4. Create key/value in your Info.plist:

```
BuildDateTime String BUILD_DATE
```

Now your Info.plist will have next record after build:

```xml
<key>BuildDateTime</key>
<string>"Wed Nov 10 01:52:49 2021"</string>
```

To access the build date string value you can use next code:

```swift
if let date = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BuildDateTime") as? String {
    print(date)
}
```

**PlistBuddy**

1. Create `Run Script` in `Build Phases` with next command:

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :BuildDateTime date `date`" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH}/Info.plist"
```

Now your Info.plist will have next record after build:

```xml
<key>BuildDateTime</key>
<date>2021-11-09T23:59:56Z</date>
```

To access the build date value you can use next code:

```swift
if let date = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BuildDateTime") as? Date {
    print(date)
}
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer, thanks. Bonus points for even providing the code to read the value inside Swift :)

Comment: Incredible that something this simple needs to be so difficult in Xcode... I can't get either of the above options to work. I've spent hours on this... after a lot of fiddling the first did add the build date, but it subsequently never changes even after a clean build. The second only works for me when I point plistbuddy at the plist *source* (not the compiled destination) and thus it shows dirty in git every time I build 

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I ended up with a bit of a hack but it has worked thus far; I used the PlistBuddy method to add the entry to my **source** plist in a run script  right at the start; I then delete the entry from the source plist in a run script at the very end, which ensures it doesn't constantly show as dirty in git. This was the only solution I could find that actually reliably works for me.